# right way to connect to Cloud SQL for production?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Over the past 6 months or so of development I've been connecting to Cloud SQL from my Java GAE app using a url like this:

"jdbc:google:rdbms://" + this.instance_name + "/" + this.database_name

Although this works reliably, I suspect with the recent changes to enable native wire protocol there might be a better / faster way.

I've tried this:
"jdbc:google:mysql://" + this.instance_name + "/" + this.database_name

...but I keep getting a "no suitable driver found" error. Is the necessary JAR included with the Eclipse plugin? If not, what do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to enable Connector/J explicitly for this. Useful link:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j